# Importing CommonJS does not destructure correctly in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

In the root of my module dependency I have a file called `form.js`:

```
module.exports = require("./dist/bundle.js").form;
```

In my project I have:

```
import { someComponent } from 'my-dependency/form';
```

Yet `someComponent` will be `undefined`.

If I do this:

```
import form from 'my-dependency/form';
console.log(form.someComponent);
```

It will output something that looks like this in the console:

```
ƒ Rr(e){var t=e.component,n=void 0===t?"input":t,r=e.rend[....]
```

Yet, if I do this, it will work:

```
import form from 'my-dependency/form';
const { someComponent } = form;
```

What am I doing wrong here and how might I achieve what I want?

Inside of my `src/form.js` file I have:

```
import someComponent from "./someComponent";
export default {
  someComponent
};
```

Inside of `src/index.js`, I have:

```
import * as form from "./form";
export default {
  form
};
```

**Probable root cause but not sure how to fix?...**

It looks like the problem caused by exporting with CommonJS and importing using the ES6 syntax.

Here is someone with a similar issue but from 4 years ago:
https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/1483

and, from 2 years ago:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11179

I've tried explicitly setting code like so but this did not seem to achieve what I want (creates a module with a default property):

```
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

It looks like reading online people will do `import * as whatever from '..'` but shouldn't destructuring work too?...

Comment: Default exports aren't imported with brackets. Try changing to `export { someComponent }`, or just `import someComponent from './....'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, either:

```
export const someComponent
```

Then:

```
import { someComponent } from 'my-dependency/form'
```

Or:

```
export default {
  someComponent
}
```

Then:

```
import someComponent from 'my-dependency/form'
```