# I'm tryng to use the destructuring on the module 'pg' to get the 'Client' but it does not work. (postgres)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Why does this work:

```
import pg from 'pg'; const { Client } = pg;
```

and this doesn't:

```
import { Client } from 'pg'
```

When I try:

```
import { Client } from 'pg'
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing CommonJS does not destructure correctly in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546863/importing-commonjs-does-not-destructure-correctly-in-es6)

Comment: or [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports)

Comment: Actually they do answer your question, and the text of the error does as well.

Comment: I know that I could use require or do it the way it's shown in the terminal, but what I want is to use import like this => import { Client } from 'pg', because in their documentation, they do the same. I just don't understand why I can't. @pilchard :/ (documentation: https://node-postgres.com/)

Comment: Looks like even the most recent version is CommonJS. If you're using Typescript you can enable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` but otherwise you need to import and then destructure. (named imports *look* like destructuring but aren't)

Comment: A more explicit duplicate: [Can I import the node-postgres module (pg) or is it CommonJS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377103/can-i-import-the-node-postgres-module-pg-or-is-it-commonjs-only)